# How do I keep id variable in pca analysis in r after running factor loadings?

Tags: r, pca

I am trying to run social capital data through a principal components analysis (pca) in r by using the following dataset: https://aese.psu.edu/nercrd/community/social-capital-resources/social-capital-variables-for-2014/social-capital-variables-spreadsheet-for-2014/view

I run the analysis just fine, but I need to merge the factor loadings onto the original dataset for further analysis and presentation. I simply need to know how I can retain the id variables when I run a pca analysis so I can merge those onto the original dataset.

I have standardized the data, and then run the code below (which I gleaned from another source). I receive what appears to be factor loadings in one column for each county in the United States, but my problem is that my original database contains the id variables for each county (FIPS codes) but the factor loadings do not.

```
calcpc <- function(variables,loadings)
{
  # find the number of samples in the data set
  as.data.frame(variables)
  numsamples <- nrow(variables)
  # make a vector to store the component
  pc <- numeric(numsamples)
  # find the number of variables
  numvariables <- length(variables)
  # calculate the value of the component for each sample
  for (i in 1:numsamples)
  {
    valuei <- 0
    for (j in 1:numvariables)
    {
      valueij <- variables[i,j]
      loadingj <- loadings[j]
      valuei <- valuei + (valueij * loadingj)
    }
    pc[i] <- valuei
  }
  return(pc)
}
xxx<-calcpc(standardisedconcentrations, socialcapital.pca$rotation[,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you computed `socialcapital.pca` as
`socialcapital.pca <- prcomp(standardisedconcentrations)`

and that `standardisedconcentrations` is equal to the standardized analysis variables *in the same order they appear in the analysis dataset*, then you can simply attach the FIPS codes (as another column or as row names) to the output PC vector created by the `calcpc()` function, since the order of the rows in the Principal Component scores is the same as the order of the rows in the original data.

Also, note two things:

1. You can avoid the two loops inside the `calcpc()` function and speed up the process by computing the PC vector using the following matrix calculation:
   `pc <- variables %*% loadings`
   assuming you call the `calcpc()` function as:
   `calcpc(standardisedconcentrations, socialcapital.pca$rotation[,1,drop=FALSE])`
   where I have added `drop=FALSE` to make sure the first column of the `rotation` attribute is preserved as a matrix with one column.
2. If you call the `princomp()` function instead of the `prcomp()` function to run Principal Component analysis, you get the principal components or the scores directly as part of the output object (in attribute `scores`).
   You just need to be aware of the differences in running PCA using `princomp()` vs. `prcomp()`, mainly, quoting the documentation:
   **princomp:** "Note that the default calculation uses divisor N for the covariance matrix."
   **prcomp:**   "Unlike princomp, variances are computed with the usual divisor N - 1."

**EDIT:** As indicated in my comment below, you could also set the rownames attribute of the analysis matrix or data frame to the `FIPS` variable in your data and the results of the analysis done by `princomp()` or `prcomp()` will contain those IDs as row names.
Ex:
Using `princomp()`:

```
rownames(standardisedconcentrations) <- FIPS
socialcapital.pca <- princomp(standardisedconcentrations)
```

Then the row names of the principal components matrix `socialcapital.pca$scores` will contain the `FIPS` codes.

Or using `prcomp()`:

```
rownames(standardisedconcentrations) <- FIPS
socialcapital.pca <- prcomp(standardisedconcentrations)
pc1 <- standardisedconcentrations %*% socialcapital.pca$rotation[,1]
```

Then the row names of `pc1` will contain the `FIPS` codes.

Comment: I guess my more basic question is: How do I retain the id variable, FIPS,in the analysis? I do not want to standardize those.

Comment: I don't see any option in the `princomp()` or `prcomp()` function where you state that you want to retain a given ID variable in the analysis. However, you can do this indirectly by assigning the ID variable as `rownames` of the analysis data frame.
e.g. If `df` is the data frame where you have imported the data from the Excel file you can do `rownames(df) <- df$FIPS`, and if you then do `df.pca <- princomp(df)` you will see the FIPS values in the output matrix with the scores `df.pca$scores`.

Comment: @SHILLATE Please consider upvoting and/or setting my answer as accepted in case you consider this solved your problem. Thanks.